# How to do statistical test on two datasets with significantly different size?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have a datasets that have 9000 records. 1000 of them belong to a certain group called A and the remaining 8000 would belong to Non-A group. What kind of statistical test can I do to test if group A is statistical different from Non-A group?

Datasets A Example:

| ID | MeanTemp |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 12 |
| 16 | 90 |

Datasets Non-A Example:

| ID | MeanTemp |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 12 |
| 12 | 12.5 |
| 13 | 78 |
| 14 | 90 |
| 15 | 80 |

Comment: Can you tell us more about your data? Any example to share?

Comment: What is meanTemp? continuous data? Do you need to make inference on a broader population or do you have the full population?

Comment: Standard tests for comparing groups such as t, Wilcoxon or Kolmogorov-Smirnov don't require sample sizes to be equal and should work here.

Answer (score 3):

Your question does not give much detail about the two population distributions you want to compare. Or about what you hope to learn by making the comparison. Discussion of the fictitious samples below may
cover what you need. If not, please provide additional information.

Here are fictitious data for 1000 temperatures for an (imaginary) northern US city
near the Pacific coast (where the ocean sometimes moderates temperatures), and 8000 temperatures for various US cities within 500 miles of
the border with Canada, but not on the west coast. Suppose temperatures are for randomly chosen days and times over several years.

```
set.seed(2021)
x = rnorm(1000, 50, 15)
summary(x); sd(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.973  39.360  50.073  50.191  60.902 102.345 
[1] 15.28842  # sample standard deviation
y = rnorm(8000, 48, 20)
summary(y); sd(y)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 -32.20   34.80   47.90   48.33   61.67  121.47 
[1] 20.19551
```

Here are boxplots of the two samples from R (`x` at bottom).

```
boxplot(x,y, horizontal=T, col="skyblue2", pch=20, notch=T)
```

[image]

From the boxplots it seems clear that sample `y` is more variable than sample `x`. Because the 'notches' in the sides of the two boxes to not overlap we might guess that the medians of the two sample differ. To check formally whether population means and variances differ significantly between the two groups, one can do tests, as shown below.

A Welch two-sample t test assumes nearly normal data, but does not assume equal variances. Even though sample means differ by only a couple of degrees,
on account of the large sample sizes, the P-value is near $0,$ so we
can reject the null hypothesis that population means are equal.

```
t.test(x,y)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x and y
t = 3.4893, df = 1473.6, p-value = 0.0004986
alternative hypothesis: 
 true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.815157 2.908511
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 50.19128  48.32945
```

Moreover, an F-test shows a significant difference in population variances.

```
var.test(x,y)

        F test to compare two variances

data:  x and y
F = 0.57308, num df = 999, denom df = 7999, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: 
 true ratio of variances is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.5230508 0.6300423
sample estimates:
ratio of variances 
         0.5730805
```

_Notes: (1) Both tests handle unequal sample sizes without difficulty.
Particularly for smaller samples, the power of these tests (ability to
detect true differences) is larger if sample sizes are equal. That is, if you have a budget for getting 100 measurements altogether from the two groups, power will be best if $n_1 = n_2 = 50.$
(2) For large sample sizes, the Welch test works well if data are only approximately normal. However, the F-test relies somewhat more heavily
on the assumption that data are sampled from normal populations. (3) There are nonparametric tests to check whether two markedly non-normal distributions have the same location. (The two-sample Wilcoxon rank sum test is one possibility.) There are also nonparametric tests for checking whether two populations are equally disperse. (4) The large numbers of 'outliers' in the boxplots should not be taken as an indication that data are not normal; large normal samples typically show such outliers.